# In Titus 2:1-2, are the roles Paul describes the “sound doctrine”?

Tags: titus

> **1** You, however, must teach what is appropriate to sound doctrine. **2** Teach the older men to be temperate, worthy of respect, self-controlled, and sound in faith, in love and in endurance.
>   *Titus 2:1-2*

Some friends of mine and I were discussing this passage. Paul had just finished talking about in Titus 1 the "detestable, disobedient, and unfit" Cretans. We were in conflict about whether Titus 2:1 was simply a conclusion of these ideas, or whether the "sound doctrine" refers to Paul's enumerations in the rest of Titus 2 of the roles of various people.

I saw [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8649/what-does-paul-mean-by-sound-doctrine-in-titus-21) which clarified a bit about what constitutes "sound doctrine", but I'm still not sure whether the rest of Titus 2 is a part of this.

Can someone clarify the original intention of the text here?

Comment: @SteveTaylor I think my question was more specific than that question (the answered I selected below doesn't really appear on that page), but I recognize that most people searching for `Titus 1` are probably wondering about "sound doctrine" more broadly. I'll mark this as duplicated for that reason.

Comment: I do agree with you, the two are somewhat different in scope, but I just don't think they're different *enough* to warrant separate questions. I've added a [new answer](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/26446/13311) to the other question which expands on Revelation Lad's answer, which you've accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion stems from how the NIV translates the passage. Here the King James makes the original clearer:

> *But speak (λάλει) thou the things which become sound doctrine: That the aged men be sober, grave, temperate, sound in faith, in charity, in patience. (Titus 2:1-2 KJV)*

The meaning of λάλει is to speak or proclaim [Strongs 2980](http://biblehub.com/greek/2980.htm).

So the instruction is to speak (V1) the things which follow. In this case the "sound doctrine" are those things which follow.